# Publishing directly to azure with multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Have a Solution with a DAL, Service Layer and an Asp.net mvc web project. When I right click and publish the web project to the "mysite.azurewebsite.net" web app I get the following error:
[image]

```
Text...
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742 for more information.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I have all the dependencies mapped and copied to local before I try and publish

Comment: Did you configure the .NET framework version (v4.5 for example) in the <httpRuntime targetFramework> attribute?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you running? Which version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: VS 2015 - .Net 4.5, The target framework is set to 4.5.2. I had also used VS2013 but it was the same result. I will also note that just deploying a sample single asp.net web project that it will deploy correctly, its only when i add the two class libraries and use this in my controllers that this issue pops up. Would i need separate " web apps" in azure for each class library?